# How to show more info when listbox changed?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I am trying to make a C# program to display album information. How do I have the information show in the fields on the right when the item in the listbox is selected?

The GUI:

[image]

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Assignment_2_S2_2014
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void closeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void saveChangesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Album information is automatically saved, if none are showing try LOAD option.");
        }

        private void loadAlbumsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                lbxAlbums.Items.Clear();
                foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("Albums.dat"))
                {
                    string[] tokens = line.Split(',');
                    lbxAlbums.Items.Add(tokens[0] + " - " + tokens[1]);
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Load Complete!");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("No Albums Found. Try Adding Some First!");
            }
        }

        private void printSelectedToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PrintDialog dlg = new PrintDialog();
            dlg.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NewAlbum frm = new NewAlbum();

            frm.Show();

        }

        private void lbxAlbums_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string a = lbxAlbums.SelectedIndex.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Handle this event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged.aspx

Comment: Is your question about getting these attributes from audio file? or is it about handling selected item change?

Comment: @Shaharyar it is using the information from the save file to load the info on the left, just need to show all info on the right.

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: So where are the attributes `title` `artist` etc stored?

Comment: @Shaharyar They are stored in a .dat file which is loaded.

Comment: Please add code to the question you are using to load file.

Comment: Not an image of the code. Copy your code and paste it in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler you need to get the selected item and extract the values from it by splitting it:

```
private void lbxAlbums_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string title, artist = "";

    title = lbxAlbums.SelectedItem.ToString().Split(new string[] { " - " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
    artist = lbxAlbums.SelectedItem.ToString().Split(new string[] { " - " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];

    //now you can use them to assign those labels
}
```